# Javascript library for drawing scale-like graph

Tags: javascript, charts, scale

As title sais. What I'm looking for is actualy more of a bar chart with only one axis and multiple bars overlapping. Sorry, hard to describe. I drew a sketch:

[Note: It's not a stacked bar chart!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovBxm.png)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found what I was looking for.

It's called a "Linear Gauge" and I realized it with chart.js using a gradient as background and hiding the y-Axis.